# Group on Extracted Value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, toad

I am trying to group on an extract value.  I am creating the start of the quarter by extracting it with Cases.  I am trying to add this Sales_Quarter to my group buy i get the error "Sales_Quarter" invalid identifier when running in Toad on an oracle sever.

```
with c_prod as (select prod_id_pri, prod_desc,prod_num from rm_mrb.V_PRODUCT_PROD_LIST)
select 'Excluded' as Status, tr.product_id, prod.prod_desc,
 sum(tr.QUANTITY) QUANTITY,  sum(total_Prescriptions) Total_#_OF_PRESCRIPTIONS, count(*) Claims
,CASE 
            When 
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Tr.Fill_Date) IN ( 
                    '1', 
                    '2', 
                    '3' )
                THEN
                    '01-01-'||EXTRACT(Year FROM Tr.Fill_Date)
            When 
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Tr.Fill_Date) IN ( 
                    '4', 
                    '5', 
                    '6' )
                THEN
                    '04-01-'||EXTRACT(Year FROM Tr.Fill_Date)
            When 
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Tr.Fill_Date) IN ( 
                    '7', 
                    '8', 
                    '9' )
                THEN
                    '07-01-' ||EXTRACT(Year FROM Tr.Fill_Date)
            ELSE '10-01-'||EXTRACT(Year FROM Tr.Fill_Date)
    End As Sales_Quarter
  from VALIUSER.ivd_transaction_record_details RD, valiuser.IVD_TRANSACTION_RECORDS TR
  left join c_prod prod on (tr.product_id=prod.prod_id_pri)
  where TR.transaction_record_id=RD.transaction_record_id
  and status='1'
  and tr.File_id in (1765)
  group by Status,Product_id,prod.prod_desc,Sales_Quarter
```

Comment: Use one more wrapper select and calculate the the values of Sales_Quarter in that select and then use it in group by

Answer (score 2):

You can group by the Year and Quarter

```
group by Status,Product_id,prod.prod_desc,EXTRACT(Year FROM Tr.Fill_Date),EXTRACT(Quarter FROM Tr.Fill_Date)
```

You could also eliminate the case statement with:

```
to_string(
 ((EXTRACT(Quarter FROM Tr.Fill_Date)-1)*3)+1) 
|| '-01-' 
|| EXTRACT(Year FROM Tr.Fill_Date)
```

Comment: Better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `GROUP BY` using a column alias the way you can in an `ORDER BY`.

Either repeat your entire expression for `Sales_Quarter` in your group by clause, or else compute it in a `WITH` clause and then select it and group by it.  I will demonstrate this later approach below:

```
with c_prod as (select prod_id_pri, prod_desc,prod_num from rm_mrb.V_PRODUCT_PROD_LIST),
extracted as (
select 'Excluded' as Status, tr.product_id, prod.prod_desc,
 tr.QUANTITY,  total_prescriptions
,CASE 
            When 
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Tr.Fill_Date) IN ( 
                    '1', 
                    '2', 
                    '3' )
                THEN
                    '01-01-'||EXTRACT(Year FROM Tr.Fill_Date)
            When 
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Tr.Fill_Date) IN ( 
                    '4', 
                    '5', 
                    '6' )
                THEN
                    '04-01-'||EXTRACT(Year FROM Tr.Fill_Date)
            When 
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Tr.Fill_Date) IN ( 
                    '7', 
                    '8', 
                    '9' )
                THEN
                    '07-01-' ||EXTRACT(Year FROM Tr.Fill_Date)
            ELSE '10-01-'||EXTRACT(Year FROM Tr.Fill_Date)
    End As Sales_Quarter
  from VALIUSER.ivd_transaction_record_details RD, valiuser.IVD_TRANSACTION_RECORDS TR
  left join c_prod prod on (tr.product_id=prod.prod_id_pri)
  where TR.transaction_record_id=RD.transaction_record_id
  and status='1'
  and tr.File_id in (1765)
)
SELECT 'Excluded' as Status, product_id, prod_desc, sales_quarter,
 sum(QUANTITY) QUANTITY,  sum(total_Prescriptions) Total_#_OF_PRESCRIPTIONS, count(*) Claims
 from extracted
  group by Status,Product_id,prod.prod_desc,Sales_Quarter
```

Comment: "You cannot GROUP BY using a column alias the way you can in an ORDER BY." -- that actually answers why the error is occurring, and how to solve it when its not as simple as changing the use of built-in functions.  Both good answers :)